# $ f(x)=f(x+1) $  and $ f(-1/x)=f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

Is there any function $f$ which would satisfy $f(x)=f(x+1)$ and $f(-1/x)=f(x)$ for every $x$ or at least positive $x$? For the widest possible domains of $x$?

If I could turn this functional equation into differential equations, I could use some approximate analytic method to get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

In a more general case, is the a function $g$ so $ f \left( \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \right) = g(x)$?

For real $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?

Comment: I think you want to ask: "Find all the function satisfy..." instead of asking "is there any function which satisfy..." since there are many functions satisfying the functional equation you stated, e.g. constant functions.

Comment: @Jose Garcia: You would want to impose additional conditions on $f$ relevant to your needs. For example, continuity everywhere is too strong, for then only the constant functions work.

Comment: What you are asking for is a modular form of weight $0$. You may want to look here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form)  for more details.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this is of interest, but if, instead of real $x$, you consider $z$ in the complex upper half plane, then the two linear fractional transformations
$$
z\to z+1,\quad z\to -1/z
$$
generate the modular group.  I.e., writing the linear fractional transformations as matrices, they generate $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.  The classical $j$ invariant 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant
is an example of a function invariant under the modular group

Comment: This neat property of the Klein invariant also makes for a good numerical algorithm for evaluating it...

Answer (score 10):

A very simple solution to these functional equations is any constant function of the form $f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$.  Let f(x)=3.  Then $f(x+1)=f(x)=f(-1/x)=3$.

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted?  If this answer does not respond to the question appropriately, I will remove it.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I can not understand why anyone would have downvoted it.

Answer (score 8):

(Edit)

You have

$$\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{x}+1}+1}=x-1,$$

so

$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)=f\left(\frac{-1}{x}+1\right)=\dots =f\left(\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{x}+1}+1}\right)=f(x-1),$$

and so you can even explicitly shift to the left. One can actually construct any [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) and so you see that the function takes the same value on all rational values (even for only a finite number of operations for each number).

Due to $f(x)=f(x\pm 1)$ you have a grid with gap distance $1$ at the right of any starting value. There the function always take the same value, i.e. $f(n)=f(0)$ for all integers. Now consider $n=-2$, then $f(1/2)=f(-2)=f(0-2)=f(0),$ and consequently also $f(1/2+n)=f(0)$. So the grid really only has distance $1/2$. We can go on and collect more point with that value. Look at numbers with bigger absolute values, like $-3:\ f(1/3)=f(-3)=f(0)$. Obviously $f(1/n)=f(0)$ for any $n$. And so in general we have $f(1/n+m)=f(0)$ for all integers $n$ and $m$. Therefore also $f(1/(1/n+m))=f(0)$, and so $f(1/(1/n+m)+k)=f(0)$ and so on.

---

Sidenote: The first condition is obviously periodicity. And regarding the other condition, notice that whenever you have an operation $g$ with $g(g(x))=x$, like it is the case for $g(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ or in fact all real functions that can be mirrored w.r.t. the $45°$ axis, then for *any* function $f$, the function $$\hat{f}(x):=f(x)+f(g(x))$$ fulfills $$\hat{f}(g(x))=f(g(x))+f(g(g(x)))=f(g(x))+f(x)=\hat{f}(x)$$

Actually, via the identity

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(g(x))\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)-f(g(x))\right),$$

all functions have a part which fullfills the relation, except the ones which fulfill the anti-relation $f(g(x))=-f(x)$ for which that part is zero.

Answer (score 2):

As stopple noted, the transformations $z \to z+1$ and $z \to -1/z$ generate the modular group.
For any two rationals $r$ and $s$ there is a transformation in this group that takes $r$ to $s$, and thus $f(r) = f(s)$.  In particular, if $f$ is continuous that says $f$ is constant.